# Count instances of string and quantity of those instances

Tags: excel, count, grouping, excel-2013

I'm trying to find a way to make my excel sheet give me result data. I have a list of string items and a quantity of that string and I want to get a total quantity of that string. Example below.

```
[ROW]    [NAME]      [QTY]                     [results]
  1        PEN         1                        [PEN]         [6]
  2        PEN         2                        [PENCIL]      [5]                   
  3        PENCIL      5                        [MARKER]      [5]
  4        MARKER      5
  5        PEN         3
```

From this Excel sheet, I want to produce results on the right from the data on the left.

Comment: Also the resulted data should be able to update automatically if I happen to change the numbers of the quantity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a built-in feature of Excel called a [Pivot Table.](http://www.contextures.com/Pubn03.html)

Comment: I was hoping to keep this contained within the excel sheet.

Comment: Im not sure how macros work, but essentially I want the result fields to update automatically when the data fields change.

Comment: Pivot forces results into a new sheet and results are not automatically updated when data is changed.

Comment: @pnuts - **Good point!**  we would an event macro to refresh the *PT* if automatic update is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `[ROW]` is in A1, create a unique list of `[NAME]` (select ColumnB, DATA > Sort & Filter - Advanced, Action Copy to another location, List range: `$B$1:$B$6` Copy to: `$G$1`, check Unique records only) then in H1 insert `[results]`, in `H2`:

```
="["&G2&"]"
```

in I2:

```
="["&SUMIF(B:B,G2,C:C)&"]"
```

and copy both formulae down to suit.

Comment: These Instructions dont seem to apply in Excel 2013